# Change colors of output log text from Django development server

Tags: django, django-dev-server

When running the django test server on a local project, can you make 400/500 errors stand out in a different color in output text?

Comment: I have colored output on OSX by default :/  What OS are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The colors can be controlled using the `DJANGO_COLORS` environment variable. See the [docs on syntax coloring](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/django-admin/#syntax-coloring).

This requires a platform which supports colors.

Comment: Where exactly do you put those export commands?  In settings.py?

Comment: They would go in your .bashrc file or in the virtualenv postactivate script if you wanted to configure the colors on a project by project basis.