# Django runserver color output

Tags: python, django, debugging

I am looking for an answer concerning the color used in the output during a session of `python2 manage.py runserver`

I'm sure that understanding why some output is yellow, blue, or pink will help me to perform better debugging.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the default palette:

```
    'ERROR':        { 'fg': 'red', 'opts': ('bold',) },
    'NOTICE':       { 'fg': 'red' },
    'SQL_FIELD':    { 'fg': 'green', 'opts': ('bold',) },
    'SQL_COLTYPE':  { 'fg': 'green' },
    'SQL_KEYWORD':  { 'fg': 'yellow' },
    'SQL_TABLE':    { 'opts': ('bold',) },
    'HTTP_INFO':         { 'opts': ('bold',) },
    'HTTP_SUCCESS':      { },
    'HTTP_REDIRECT':     { 'fg': 'green' },
    'HTTP_NOT_MODIFIED': { 'fg': 'cyan' },
    'HTTP_BAD_REQUEST':  { 'fg': 'red', 'opts': ('bold',) },
    'HTTP_NOT_FOUND':    { 'fg': 'yellow' },
    'HTTP_SERVER_ERROR': { 'fg': 'magenta', 'opts': ('bold',) },
```

Comment: How did you find it?

Answer (score 7):

Haven't done it by myself, but here are some links which will help:

- django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#syntax-coloring) on django-admin commands coloring
- [Better color scheme for django dev server](http://web.archive.org/web/20150906070009/http://alex.koval.kharkov.ua/blog/better-color-scheme-for-django-dev-server/)
- [Change colors of output log text from Django development server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027654/change-colors-of-output-log-text-from-django-development-server)

Basically, colors are set via `DJANGO_COLORS` environment variable:

```
export DJANGO_COLORS="light"
```

Answer (score 2):

To add a bit more to Pavel's answer, here is the location of the file that contains the default color settings on a Mac (OSX 10.11 El Capitan). Note: this is for Django 1.9.

The color palette is located in a file called: **termcolors.py**, which is located in:

```
/django/utils/
```

I installed Django in a virtual environment ("venv1"), so for me, the **termcolors.py** file is located here:

```
~/.virtualenvs/venv1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/termcolors.py
```